# integral of 1/(sqrt(e^x)) from 0 to infinity(Improper integral)

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm taking Calculus 1 course and I'm having problems with the following integrals(Improper integrals)

1. $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \frac1{\sqrt{e^x}}$ dx
2. $\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^\frac1x$ dx
3. $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty (1+\sin x)\cdot e^{-x}$ dx

Answer for third:

$\displaystyle\int_1^\infty (1+\sin x)\cdot e^{-x}$ dx < $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty (2)\cdot e^{-x}$ dx = 1

Therefor it  be can bounded

Thanks for your help-(helpful sites will also be appriciated)

Comment: What did you try so far? can you calculate the indefinite integrals?

Comment: I've understood the first one.The indefinite integral of the second is (e^(1/x + 1))/lnx but I can't work with that.

Comment: The third I tried in parts but did not succeed-appreciate your help thanks

Comment: For 3, consider $\int (1+e^{ix})e^{-x}dx$ since $\exp(ix)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ we take the imaginary part of the resulting integral...

Comment: There is some method that may be helpful for the third. You denote the integral as I, integrating by parts twice, and get some variation of I. Then you have equation in I, that you can solve. In additional, if you want to check your results, you can use Wolfram Alpha:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1+to+infinity+(1%2Bsin(x))e%5E(-x)+dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT for 1:

$\displaystyle \frac1{\sqrt{e^x}}=\frac1{(e^x)^\frac12}=e^{-\frac12x}$

Answer (score 0):

The first integrand can be written as $e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$. Then, you can $u$-substitute $u=-\frac{x}{2}$.

Are you sure you wrote down the second integrand right?

The third integrand's $\int e^{-x}$ term is straightforward to do. $\int e^{-x} \sin x$ can be done via integration by parts (similar to the way in [this link](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/byparts/Example3/Example3.html)) or a [table](http://integral-table.com/integral-table.html#SECTION00009000000000000000) (See #117 and u-substitute $u=-x$ first, and note $\sin(-x) = - \sin(x)$ to match the form of the integrands).

Comment: yes'I'm positive that I wrote the second integral right.

Comment: I have not succeeded to do the third(tried in parts but nothing good came from there).thanks for your help